# How to enque js script in footer that are not in .js file?

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I do have code that is js script inline together with php script is their possible way to enque it to footer without puting it on .js file

To clear explanition on my question here is my example code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: <?php echo $option1 ?>,
            generateNextPrev: <?php echo $option2 ?>
        });
                    //some other script 

    });
</script>
```

Without putting that code in single js, How can I enque it? I see the documentation about enque script usage which only needs 'src'

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
     $handle
    ,$src
    ,$deps
    ,$ver
    ,$in_footer 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just hook into `wp_footer` and print out your script.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse64534_script');
function wpse64534_script()
{
    ?>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: <?php echo $option1 ?>,
                generateNextPrev: <?php echo $option2 ?>
            });
                        //some other script 

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I tried this metthod with passing variable on function but give me error   Missing argument 2 for function name, my function looks like this function wpse64534_script($option1, $option2){ //some code }

Comment: That's because `wp_footer` doesn't pass any variables to its hooked functions.  You need to do some research on how the Hooks api works -- specifically look at how `do_action` and `apply_filters` work. If you need variables for elsewhere you can either use globals (bad idea) or use an object (a class) to contain all the related functionality.